# Graphical svn client for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, gui, svn

Any graphical svn clients working under 16.04?  I had kdesvn before, but its no longer available from the packages.  Neither is rapidsvn.  Console is fine, but always nice to have GUI when searching through a non-local repo.

Comment: what about [this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/universe/base/rapidsvn) ?

Answer (score 20):

The best client for your purposes would be RabbitVCS, a great Version Control System  (VCS) utility that has a more than decent package in the Ubuntu Repositories. To install the *complete* package use the following from  Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-cli rabbitvcs-core rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-nautilus
```

The Nautilus interface gives graphical access to git and hg repositories *as well as* the svn access you were after. Don't want see hg and git? See the ingenious solution [here...](https://askubuntu.com/q/484887/57576)

Snapshot below shows RabbitVCS working with the MPlayer svn repository:

[image]

I would recommend also having a look at the *remote* repository browser available from within the Nautilus screen that works well without a local repository loaded. Again showing the MPlayer svn repository, this time with the remote repository browser:

[image]

**References:**

- [RabbitVCS Home Page](http://rabbitvcs.org/)
- [Ask Ubuntu: Show only svn in RabbitVCS context menu](https://askubuntu.com/q/484887/57576)

Comment: Thanks, Rapid showed up after I enabled additional options within the Software & Updates menu under settings.  Seems as though the package didn't show up until I enabled one of the Other Software packages.

Answer (score 1):

[SmartGit](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) is a graphical Git client with support for **SVN** and Pull Requests for **GitHub** and Bitbucket. SmartGit runs on Windows, macOS and Linux.

Comment: It should be noted it's not free for commercial usage.